# Does FUSE have any specific cache interaction?

Tags: filesystems, cache, fuse

I'm a bit lost in how kernel caches work in general, so generic cache information is fine too, but I'm specifically working on FUSE.

So, I read that the kernel looks up a file/directory via VFS using dentries and inodes. There are dcaches and inode caches.

That's all I understand so far, and I'm struggling with any deeper information.

Any information is fine, but here are some specific questions.

For example, you have a `read` function in FUSE that just directly calls the `read` libc function to a specific path.

1. Are there any FUSE-specific caches in works there?
2. If we assume the read path is inside an ext4 filesystem, then are ext4-specific caches being used?
3. What happens when the FUSE `read` function stops calling libc `read` during runtime? Are caches going to affect it at all?